# recognize interlocutors in a text in Python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a chalnging problem which I couldn't find a solution for it.
I have a pandas dataframe which contains conversations and the speakers
You can see the dataframe in this image
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXkF0.png)

The column Conversation contains the conversation between two or more people and the column Speaker associates each word with the person who said it.
For this exemple, Hi how are you sir? is the persone number one: Hi (1) how (1) are (1) you  (1) sir? (1)
That's why we have five consecutive 1 in the Speaker column.
I’m fine thanks: is the second person:  I'm (2) fine (2) thanks (2).
That's why we have three consecutive 2 in the Speaker column.
And so on...
I'd like to add the indicator for every person after each sentence over the whole pandas dataframe like this: Hi how are you sir? (1) I’m fine thanks (2) how can I help you? (1) Can you give me one bottle of water? (2)
I tried many loops but I couldn't solve it.
Anyone has a solution please?
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the future please copy your DataFrame and put it in a Markdown format as it is inconvenient to look at an image and then reproduce the DataFrame. Following is a code snippet that will accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
for row in range(len(df)):

    # Splitting conversation into respective words based on spaces
    conversation_tokens = df['Conversation'][row].split(" ") 

    # ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']
    speaker_tokens = list(str(df['Speaker'][row])) 

    # Variable to store new conversation with indicators for each person
    new_conversation = ""

    # Looping through until the last word in the conversation
    for i in range(1, len(speaker_tokens)-1):
        new_conversation += f'{conversation_tokens[i]} '
        
        # Checking to see if next word is said by the same person
        if(speaker_tokens[i] != speaker_tokens[i+1]):
            new_conversation += f'({speaker_tokens[i]}) '

    # Taking care of the last word in the conversation
    new_conversation += f'{ conversation_tokens[-1]} ({speaker_tokens[-1]})'

    # Replacing the conversation with the new conversation with indicators
    df.iat[row, df.columns.get_loc('Conversation')] = new_conversation
```

Comment: Hi @saksham Gupta
Thanks for your response.
I've tried this code it works but there is no space beween words.
The result that I get is Hihowareyousir?1I’m fine thanks2howcanIhelpyou?1Canyougivemeonebottleofwater?2
Is there any way to get the results with spaces between words?
Thanks

Comment: Please check if you have accidentally removed the spaces while copying the lines 

```new_conversation += f'{conversation_tokens[i]} '```  

Note: There's a space in between the last curly bracket and the apostrophe